# Finding a string within 2 files and then moving the files. Batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, if-statement

I recently asked a question about finding files with the same ID and then moving them.
Although the files I am moving do not have the same ID. Instead they have the same string within the files. 
Here is the code I have for finding the same ID of files

```
ECHO OFF
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

set "source=C:SORCEFOLER"
set "destBIAK=C:BIAKFOLER"
set "destBIPO=C:BIPOFOLDER"
set "POfile=BIPO"
SET "AKfile=BIAK"

pushd "%source%"
for %%F in ("%POfile%*") do (
  set "setID=%%F"
  set "setID=!setID:%POfile%=!"
  if exist "%AKfile%!setID!" robocopy /mov "%source%" "%destbiak%" "%%F" 
  if exist "%AKfile%!setID!" robocopy /mov "%source%" "%destbipo%" "%AKfile%!setID!"
)
popd
```

Like I said, I need to actually find a string that matches in the two different and then move them based on the the string.

Here is a example of the beginning of the first file

```
H|0003341369|20131123
```

I can not post the entire PO file because it contains customer names and addresses that are proprietary information of the person I am making the file for.

here is the entire AK file

```
0003341369|SO-02052|20131124|A|
```

That just a bunch of numbers. Notice that digits 3 through 12 of the PO file match digits 1 though 10 of the AK file.

There are multiple AK files and PO files in one folder.

I was thinking that the script would find the ID of the AK file, search all the PO files until it finds the one that matches and then moves them.

I have looked at several scripts that search for a string, they then output the file name with the string to a certain file. I cant figure out how to output this as a variable.
Thanks

Comment: _There are multiple AK files and PO files in one file_: No way... Are those files concatenated in one? Or did you mean they are in the same folder or what else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should take the first term in every `AK.*` file (the characters before the first `|` character such as `0003341369` ) and search for it in every `PO.*` file.

If it finds the term inside two `||` characters (such as `|0003341369|` ) then it will move those files to a folder - and after comparing all `PO.*` files it will move the `AK.xxx` file to the same folder.

```
@echo off
for %%a in (AK.*) do (
   MD "folder %%~na"
      for /f "delims=|" %%b in ('type "%%a" ') do (
        for %%c in (PO.*) do findstr "|%%b|" "%%c" >nul && move "%%c" "folder %%~na" >nul
      )
   move "%%a" "folder %%~na"
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that as soon as I can. I should then be able to moove the AK and PO files to separate folders from there, right?

Comment: The aim of the batch file is to move them into separate folders already.  If the search term can be at the beginning or end of a line inside the `PO.*` files then it will need to be modified.